# Send text if editText contains text or record Audio with ontouchlistener

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener, android-mediarecorder

My app has a bottom bar with a Send/record button. my goal is by using `OntouchListener` is: when the editText does not contain any text to enable recording function if editText contain text to ignore recording function and just add text to a list. how can I archive this?

**The same function used inside WhatsApp record/send button (Chat activity)**

I have tried using the code below, where `send` is the red button

[image]

(some variables have been declared in the outside this code)

```
send.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                send.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.send));
                String string = editText.getText().toString();
                dati.add(new ModelloDati(tlDATE,""));
                dati.add(new ModelloDati(tlTEXT,string));
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(dati.size());
                editText.getText().clear();
            }
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bar_rec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                outputFile =  
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "
/recording.3gp";

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chronometer.start();
                recorder.start();

            }else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bar_rec.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                dati.add(new ModelloDati(tlAUDIO,outputFile));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(dati.size());
            closeKeyboard();

            return false;
        }



    });
```

Comment: What's the problem? What the code is doing right now?

Comment: @RicardoA. this code should check if there is text inside the `editText` if `editText`contains text different from space,  text from `editText` gets added to a List but if `editText`is empty or contains only spaces, this button should instead start recording process on button press and stop recording on button release.

Comment: I think you need a `LongClickListener` not `OnTouchListener` to mimic whatsapp send button ..

Comment: @ADM but how do I mimic press and release?

Comment: What I mean is... it's throwing an exception? It is behaving different from how it should behave? It just doesn't do what it should do...? I think you should put a return in the end of the if statement that checks if the text isn't empty.